# Is it possible to use iOS autocorrect library on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, autocorrect

I want to implement multi language autocomplete in Swift app. Is it possible to use IOS native autocorrect library to obtain the list of possible words?

Answer (score 3):

[`UITextChecker`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/) has some methods relevant to what you are looking for. Also, take a look at [this NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/uitextchecker/) about using `UITextChecker`.